# Spring MVC returns a 404 because of a wrong InternalResourceViewResolver view name

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am new on Spring MVC & Boot. I can open http://localhost:8088/postList but I am experiencing Whitelabel Error Page error when opening http://localhost:8088/post/1 . I can't find my mistake. Can you say it?

My project structure

[image]

My InternalResourceViewer:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PostController 
{

@Autowired
PostService postService;

@RequestMapping(value="/post/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView list(@PathVariable("id") int id){

    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("post");

    Post postItem=postService.getPostById(id);
    mav.addObject("postItem",postItem);

    mav.addObject("postItem",postItem);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/postList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView postlist(){

    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("postList");
    mav.addObject("postList",postService.listPosts());

    return mav;
}


}
```

My PostList:

[image]

My Post viewing page:

[image]

My postList.jsp taglibs and contents:

> ```
>     <div class="row">
>
>       <c:if test="${not empty postList}">
>           <c:forEach var="postItem" items="${postList}">
>               <div class="col-lg-8">
>
>                   <h1><a href="<c:url value='/post/${postItem.id}' />">${postItem.header}</a></h1>
>
>                   <p class="lead">
>                       by <a href="#">${postItem.user_id}</a>
>                   </p>
>
>                   <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>${postItem.upddate}</p>
>
>                    <hr>
>               </div>
>           </c:forEach>
>         </c:if>
> ```

Comment: Show us the `postList.jsp` content with the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you need a leading `/` in your `InternalResourceViewResolver` prefix. So

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

The long answer is that Spring MVC uses the `InternalResourceViewResolver` to generate a [`View`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html), in this case a [`JstlView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html). Spring MVC then tries to render this `View`.

To do so, it uses the view name (the prefix, the name in your `ModelView`, and the suffix, ie. `WEB-INF/views/post.jsp`), as a path and tries to retrieve a `RequestDispatcher` by delegating to [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-).

> **The pathname specified may be relative**, although it cannot extend
>   outside the current servlet context. **If the path begins with a `"/"` it
>   is interpreted as relative to the current context root.** This method
>   returns `null` if the servlet container cannot return a
>   `RequestDispatcher`.

Since you don't have a leading `/`, it is relative to the current path, ie. `/post/1`. That makes it `/post/WEB-INF/views/post.jsp`. And since you have no such resource relative to the `ServletContext`, your Servlet container returns a 404.

Comment: How I missed it. Thank you so much Sotirios. It's solved when I added to "/" head of prefix.